# C# Read specific line from file and take text from it

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm creating a program that allows you to manage a game server, now the main settings of it exist in a file called `server.properties`. I'm making a form which is able to change these settings. However, I want to be able to load the current settings into different things.

For example, if a line is `spawn-npcs=true` in the `server.properties` file, I want to be able to apply that to a `CheckBox` and make the `CheckBox Checked`. Or if something uses numbers then a `TextBox` would need to contain that so if a line is `server-name=Funhuas` in the `server.properties` file a certain `TextBox` would need to only read `Funhaus`.

I am using this code to read the lines I want:

```
string line = File.ReadLines("server.properties").Skip(14).Take(1).First();
```

And I am using this code to change the value of that line:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("server.properties");
lines[6] = "spawn-npcs=" + textBox1.Text;
File.WriteAllLines("server.properties", lines);
```

The code above seemingly works fine however. Also, all this data will be entered when the user presses a `Save` button. Hope I've provided enough info, thanks!

Comment: Only bit of info that seems to be missing is "What is the question".

Comment: Are you asking how to save the values back to the server.properties file?

Comment: No, I know how to write the values back to the file, apologies for the clarity, what I'm trying to say is if for example line 4 in the properties file is this: "spawn-npcs=true" I want to take just the "true" part of that statement and put it in a textbox

Comment: and why dont you just split the string and take everything after = ? (if you are sure there`s a value in it)

line.Split('=')[1];

Comment: `var value = line.Split(new[]{'='})[1];`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!